# Combination of Flowplayer and Dexterity throwing errors

Tags: plone, flowplayer

I have defined a content type in dexterity that has a number of RichText fields in it, and this was working fine. I then added collective.flowplayer into my install. This seems to add an adapter so that it can detect if content has an audio or video player div tag embeded in it, which all makes sense. But now I can't edit or create an instance of one of my dexterity types. The adapter throws an exception complaining that the type cannot be adapted to IPrimaryFieldInfo, and the dexterity content type cannot be saved.

Taking the clue from another SO question, I derived the dexterity content type from both plone.directives.form.Schema and plone.rfc822.interfaces.IPrimaryFieldInfo. A different exception this time in collective.flowplayer.dexterity's update_media_info function, which I could work around by changing:

```
    if info.value is not None:
```

to

```
    if hasattr(info, 'value') and info.value is not None:
```

which is a bit too hacky for me to be happy with.

Is this a known problem, or is this just some versioning nightmare?

Comment: Rather than hacking at the collective.flowplayer.dexterity have added the following to my dexterity interface: `form.omitted('value')` and then `value = schema.Bytes(default=None)`. This defines the value attribute in the instance of the dexterity object so the above code doesn't bork. Still not pretty, but it does get me over this hurdle for now.